# Randomize LuisDialog answer

Tags: c#, .net, random, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

Hi guys im trying to use Random.Next to try to randomize the answer of luis. Unfortunately it doest seems to work, it always returns zero.

```
[LuisIntent("Age")]
    public async Task Age(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int randomNumber = random.Next(0, 1);
        List<string> Answers = new List<string>();
        Answers.Add("Are you serious?");
        Answers.Add("A million!I am million years old!Any more questions?");

        string message = Answers[randomNumber];
        await context.PostAsync(message);

        context.Done(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from your random function. As, `random.Next(m,n)` is a random number `>=m` and `<n`, so `random.Next(0,1)` just generate 0. Hence, you should change it to `random.Next(0,2)`.